# How many throws to get 50% probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm new to Probability and I'm struggling to come up with a method to solve this question. If a basketball player has a 5% chance of throwing the ball to the basket, how many throws he need to make to be assured of having 50% chance of throwing it to the basket?

Comment: Hint:  easier to find the opposite.  i.e. what's the most he can throw and still have a 50% chance of missing every time.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for each shot, $$P(S)=0.05$$

Because each shot is independent , the probability of each shot is also 0.05.

The probability that he misses the shot is $P(M)=0.95$

The probability that he misses 10 in a row is $$(0.95)^{10}=0.5988$$

the probability that he misses 13 in a row is $0.5133$

and the probability that he misses 14 in a row is  $0.4876$

So the probability that he doesn't miss 14 in a row i.e.,he makes one is $1-0.4876=0.5124$

Comment: Thanks! But the question asks for how many throws he need to make to achieve 50% probability. Without directly starting from 10, and going forward, is there a equation that I could used ?

Comment: You want to solve the equation $0.95^x=0.5$ and round that number up. It follows that $x=\log_{0.95}(0.5)\approx 13.513$. That gives you the answer directly.

Comment: Yes but understand you cannot shoot 13.5 times

Comment: @Quality Hence “and round that number up”. Your answer is completely correct but OP was asking for another way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We know that on the first throw he has a .95 probability of *missing*.
Thus, on his second turn, he has a .95^2 probability of missing.

We can generalize the probability of making a shot is to P(t) where t is the number of throws is:

$$P(t) = 1 - (.95) ^ t$$

We want P(t) to be at least .5

$$.5 \leq 1 - (.95) ^ t$$
$$-0.5 \leq - (.95) ^ t$$
$$0.5 \geq (.95) ^ t$$

Thus, we calculate that if $t=13$, we get $.5\leq(.95)^t\text{ (which is 0.5133)}$, not what we are looking for.

But if $t=14$, we do not have $.5\leq(.95)^t\text{ (which is 0.4877)}$, this is true, so he need to take $\boxed{14\text{ shots}}$.